# Best SEO practice to redirect wrong URLs with mixed langage in it

Tags: seo, url-rewriting, joomla3

a bad plugin generated some wrong path that returned 404 errors when switching language on Joomla website. The plugin problem is solved (I removed it), now I just want to redirect this few errors to get everything clean.

Here is what happened :

- User was on page `/en/englishcontent`
- When switching to german langage, the URL retured was `/de/englishcontent/id-germancontent`
- In case of long path, i got something like : `/de/english-category/english-subcat/englishcontent/id-german-category/id-german-subcat/id-germancontent`

So i have two langages in this URLs, and the SEF part is in the wrong langage.What's the best SEO practice : should I redirect to german content (the landing page) or to english content (the starting page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language was the content in?

If the broken link had english content, redirect there. And vice versa.

If there was no content - then it won't matter. Make sure you have the hreflang references either in your HTML or sitemap, then flip a coin. If the broken links are indexed by Google and are using 301 redirects then the equity will soon be absorbed by the page you've redirected to. The index can then sort which language the person is searching in and produce the appropriate alt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My pages and sitemaps have hreflang, and pages got canonical tag in case of bad crawl.
I'll use 301 redirects via htaccess pages to match the good content in the good language, based on the lang prefix/subfolder.